# Drupal 7: Contact form not floating to the right

Tags: drupal-7, contact-form

I am trying to create a contact form with Google Maps on the left side and the form on the right. I am using the contact form module.

The problem is the maps is positioned correctly however the form won't float to the right.

[image]

Can I get some help on what I'm missing?

Here is the CSS:

```
.page-contact section#block-system-main {
    float:right;
    width: 40%;
}
.page-contact .block-google-maps {
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    min-height: 500px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the html and css?

Comment: Sorry still new to Drupal 7 am using the contact form module, where is the html located at for this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using absolute positioning.

```
position: absolute;
right: 100px;
top: 110px;
```